# Access another class column from a pointer - Parse

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, tableview

I'm having nightmares with this.

I have one Parse Class named `Transactions` which has 3 pointers to each class:

[image]

Here is the Class `User`

[image]

Now what I'm trying to do is a `CustomTableView` that shows all the `Transactions` and I want to put the `Username` inside the cell. Like This:

[image]

The problem is that I can't find the right query to get this information using those pointers. Nothing works...What query give me the username of that transaction? Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're looking for all the transactions:

```
var query = PFQuery(className:"Transaction")
query.includeKey("PointerUser")
query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {
    (objects: [AnyObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in

    if error == nil {
        // The find succeeded.
        println("Successfully retrieved \(objects!.count) scores.")
        // Do something with the found objects
        if let objects = objects as? [PFObject] {
            for object in objects {
                //because we used the include key command
                //we can now access the user associated with PointerUser
                println(object["PointerUser"]["Username"])
            }  
        }
    } else {
        // Log details of the failure
        println("Error: \(error!) \(error!.userInfo!)")
    }
}
```

Comment: Interesting...This may solve my problem, but i get this error: "Cannot subscript a value of type 'AnyObject?' with an index of type 'String'" at "Println"

Comment: I have solved the problem with " println(object["PointerUser"]?["Username"])" Is that ok?

Comment: I have used your code to pass the `objects` into an array named `queryArray`. How can I access "pointerUser.username"?

Comment: Just loop through queryArray and for each object, "object," use ["PointerUser"]["Username"], just like before.

Comment: Can you take a look? http://pastebin.com/PbtcjQ7v

As it is, give me an error when ["PointerUser"]["Username"]  "Cannot assign a value of type 'AnyObject??' to a value of type 'String?'" (I can open a new question if you want) Thank you for you help :)